# i want to manage time for currently playing song,i need block for that

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I want to make player where i can play song and manage time for that song. I need a method with block where three things returned

1)Elapsed play time

2)Remaining time

3)Percentage of Elapsed time.

Block should look like

```
 andBlock:^(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished){
 NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)timeRemaining;
        NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
        NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
        NSInteger eti = (NSInteger)elapsedTime;
        NSInteger eseconds = eti % 60;
        NSInteger eminutes = (eti / 60) % 60;
}
```

I need simple method for time management with above block.